# jQuery: switch on off effect confusion

Tags: jquery, css, switch-statement

I have some problem

> .onoff switch below one .on and .off, off in the CSS opacity: 0;

I want to get the effect is only one on, other is off, and can switch ONOFF.

now it confusion, I dont know how to do it...

help me please.

http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/2924/

```
$(document).on('click', '.onoff', function() {
  if ($(this).parents().siblings().find('.off').css("opacity") == "0") {
    $(this).parents().siblings()
      .find('.on').animate({marginLeft: '+=12px',opacity: 1},250)
      .next('.off').animate({marginLeft: '-=12px',opacity: 0}, 250);
  };

  if (!$(this).hasClass("isonoff")) {
    $(this).find('.on').animate({marginLeft: '-=12px',opacity: 0},250)
      .next('.off').animate({marginLeft: '+=12px',opacity: 1}, 250);
    $(this).addClass("isonoff");
  } else {
    $(this).find('.on').animate({marginLeft: '+=12px',opacity: 1},250)
      .next('.off').animate({marginLeft: '-=12px',opacity: 0}, 250);
    $(this).removeClass("isonoff");
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/2929/

```js
$(document).on('click', '.onoff', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("isonoff")) {
    $(this).find('.on').animate({marginLeft: '-=12px',opacity: 0},250)
      .next('.off').animate({marginLeft: '+=12px',opacity: 1}, 250);
    $(this).addClass("isonoff");
  } else {
    $(this).find('.on').animate({marginLeft: '+=12px',opacity: 1},250)
      .next('.off').animate({marginLeft: '-=12px',opacity: 0}, 250);
    $(this).removeClass("isonoff");
    
    var index = $(this).closest('.post').index();

    $('.onoff').each(function(){
     if(index != $(this).closest('.post').index()){
     $(this).find('.on').animate({marginLeft: '-=12px',opacity: 0},250)
      .next('.off').animate({marginLeft: '+=12px',opacity: 1}, 250);
     $(this).addClass('isonoff');
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```css
.post {
  width: 666px;
  height: 111px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: start;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.onoff {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  background: #abcdef;
}

.on {
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 13px;
  background: #abc456;
}

.off {
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #defabc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <div class="vid">
    <h3 class="video">video 1</h3>
    <div class="onoff">
      <i class="on">on</i>
      <i class="off">off</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <div class="vid">
    <h3 class="video">video 2</h3>
    <div class="onoff">
      <i class="on">on</i>
      <i class="off">off</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <div class="vid">
    <h3 class="video">video 3</h3>
    <div class="onoff">
      <i class="on">on</i>
      <i class="off">off</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <div class="vid">
    <h3 class="video">video 4</h3>
    <div class="onoff">
      <i class="on">on</i>
      <i class="off">off</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: good job man, butttt, This not i what.... look this http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/2930/  it good,but very slow, and one "on" click other "off" need click twice, why?